# How do I mosaic several WorldView-2 images into single image in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, worldview-2

I have downloaded multiple WorldView-2 images that were outlined by an AOI, but it is unclear to me if it is possible to combine two overlapping images into a single image for downstream data analysis.  I have been unable to find a workflow for doing this. I would preferably like to perform this task using ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Do they have projection already ? If not, then what projection are you aiming for ?

Comment: I would lilkely use UTM, but the imagery as downloaded from WV-2 is WGS 1984.

Comment: You said you had an access to WorldView-2 Imagery ...what do you mean by that ?

Comment: I should have simply said I that I have downloaded images from WorldView-2. I have edited my question for clarity.

Comment: - It's ok not to worry about it

Answer (score 1):

If the images were acquired on the same day, you can usually simply combine using the tool called 'Mosaic To New Raster' (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/mosaic-to-new-raster.htm), while keeping track of NoData values.
If the images were not acquired on the same day, combining them is not recommended, as the values will be rather different and a simple mosaic would not be a useful data layer for downstream data analysis. You could try to atmospherically correct such data, but it won't be easy to make the data fully comparable meaning that it'll be difficult to make a good single data layer.